# AssetManager libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

i'm trying to make a loading page for my game.
my code its like this:

```
manager = new AssetManager();
game = new Game(level);
game.startLoadingTextures(manager);

public void startLoadingTextures(AssetManager manager){
    manager.load("data/background.png" ,Texture.class);
}
```

in a update function i have this:

```
if (manager.update()){
    game.setTexture(manager);
}
```

what is setTexture function ? i get all textures from manager.

```
public void setTexture(AssetManager manager) {
    System.out.println("entered here");
    background = manager.get("data/background.png" ,Texture.class);
}
```

and i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.smeurares.game.Loading.update(Loading.java:31)
```

line 31 is `game.setTexture(manager)`, and i get this eror before entering in the function because `System.out.println("entered here");` is not appearing in console.

what i've done wrong ?

Comment: `game` must be `null` until you hit line 31. Use the debugger and go through your code step by step to find out why it is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh.. ty noone, that was it, game wasn't declared.. because it should be this.game = new  Game(level), didint thinked about it...